# roundabout - limit numbers of items displayed at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel

I just installed roundabout and love it. Only problem is that my carroussel has over 50 images so it looks really ugly.

I'm desperatly looking for a way to limit it to display only 5 items at same time maximum.

In other words, i want a carroussel that looks exactly like this: http://bogdanrosu.com/themeforest/novux/php/index-roundabout.php

But when i add 50 images here's how it looks: http://www.alterweb.ca/roundabout/

Comment: The example you want to look like *only has 4 images*. Can you clarify why you'd place 50 images in your page but only show 5?

Comment: i don't want to show more than 5 at same time or else it looks overloaded when i have 50 images. the other images should show when you scroll through the images in the caroussel

Comment: Is a CoverFlow type of plugin like [this](http://www.jcoverflip.com/demo) or [this](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/) a better match for what you want to achieve?